# Is WebGL clear() forcable?

Tags: javascript, webgl

This JScript / WebGL snippet should color a canvas yellow.

```
gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

It does so in FF and Chrome. IE 11 however seems to call clear() when it feels like it, more than often just swapping buffers instead(?!). A lot of times the canvas background will be white, causing severe flickering. On page load it does not call clear() at all.

Is it possible to force a clear()? And do I understand the OpenGL specs right, if I think this is buggy?

---

*while creating the context with the attribute { preserveDrawingBuffer: true } mitigates the problem, it comes with decreased performance and is no fix for the initial page load... and here's a snippet.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv");

var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") ||
         canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", { preserveDrawingBuffer: true });

gl.clearColor(1, 1, 0.5, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

function refresh() {
  gl.clearColor(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

var button = document.getElementById("refresh");
button.onclick = refresh;
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="150" height="50" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"></canvas>
<br>
<button id="refresh">refresh!</button>
```

Comment: Microsoft refused to implement WebGL for years due to 'security reasons', since they recently added its support, it's normal it's buggy.

Comment: File a bug: http://issues.microsoftedge.com/

Comment: Note: In your code you're asking for `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` only if it fails to create the context with "webgl".

Comment: Ah, thanks Pierre for the history and thinking it's a bug, too. :)

And thanks @gman for the link! Wouldn't have known where to file. On your note: that's by design. It's IE falling back to "experimental-webgl" and it's IE that needs the little extra <3.

Comment: "WebGL is partially supported in Internet Explorer 11" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL

Comment: example of article which relate the fact they didn't want to integrate webgl before: http://www.winrumors.com/microsoft-refuses-to-endorse-webgl-labels-it-harmful/

Comment: make them work on google chrome and firefox, don't care about IE support (since it's not a contract with an enterprise ... )